# External driver for LTC2946 - device_property_read_u32 issue

Tags: drivers, kernel, smbus

I created my own module driver for ltc2946 based on compiled-in ltc2945 module.

I load my module using  # insmod ltc2946.ko and instantiate device using:

echo ltc2946 0x6f >  /sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-0/new_device

Question is how to pass parameter/property accessed in module by using : device_property_read_u32 ( ).

I have tried :

- /etc/modprobe.d/ltc2946.conf with "options ltc2946 parameter=xx"
- passing parameters with insmod like insmod ltc2946.ko parameter=xx

Somebody adviced me to use modprobe instead insmod , but I can't cause I need to pass module location.

My setup is x86 based with ACPI description, so I am not sure where I should pass it.
Via ACPI definition/tree  ?

Any idea ?

Best regards

Adam Górski